# Post request to page, not executing success function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in my javascript file:

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        url: '/',
        data: {test: 'This is some random data.'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(){
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('err');
        }
});
```

in Node I have the following:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res){
    console.log(req.body.test);
});
```

my command console is logging correctly the json object, but my webpage is not executing the on success function. I do not understand why if the data is being passed and received properly the error function is being called in my ajax request?

Comment: You are telling `$.ajax` to expect a json response.... but not returning anything from server. Use `error` arguments to get more details

Comment: There is no error. errorThrown is an empty string, and error status says 'error'

Comment: Can you try sending a response `res.json({"foo": "bar"});` after the `console.log`

Comment: @GaryJohnson that worked. Can you explain to me why?

Comment: In your `ajax` request you have this line `dataType: 'json',` this means that you are expecting to receive a `json` response. It does not mean you are sending `json` - which is a common misunderstanding. So in your `node` code you need to send back a `json` response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node js side you have to give a response to the request, otherwise the client side can't know how it goes and so can't trigger success or error callback :

```
app.post('/', function (req, res){
    console.log(req.body.test);
    res.end();
    // or to send json back
    // res.json({hello: 'world'});
    // to go in error callback just send a request with a status code > 400
    // res.status(400).end('bad request');
});
```

You can only send one response.

Comment: res.json worked, but not res.end. Can you explain to me why?

Comment: res.end alone doesn't work? strange, maybe it is something going on client side, like jquery